# Customizing MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone

is it possible to change the language from english to deustch for title send and cancel button and also "to","cc","Bcc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will be in German if your app supports German localization and the target device is configured to German.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please press the ✔ next to it.